# How to troubleshoot nginx configuration for a working backend but non-functional frontend?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, nginx, next.js

I am trying to deploy my react-nextjs application in digitalocean and I keep getting this error when I open this: `sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` :
`2023/05/27 15:42:26 [error] 701#701: *58 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XXX.XX.XX.XX, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/", host: "XX.XXX.XXX.X"`

When I run in my browser: XX.XXX.XXX.X/api it works means the backend is working but the front end part doesn't work when I run XX.XXX.XXX.X only.

this is my nginx config :

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

location /{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}



    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
}
```